# How can I fill a datatable from an excel listobject table

Tags: c#, excel

My main problem is getting the information from my list object in the excel spreadsheet. For some reason it wont convert the string to int see where I have commented. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static DataTable excelDerivedAssembliesDT(string excelDir, int jobID)
{

 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 var excelApp = new Excel.Application();

 try
 {
 excelApp.Visible = false;
 excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelDir);
 Excel.ListObject vstoListObject = excelApp.Worksheets[1].ListObjects[1];

　DataColumn assemblyID = new DataColumn();
 assemblyID.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
 assemblyID.ColumnName = "assemblyID";
 assemblyID.AutoIncrement = true;
dt.Columns.Add(assemblyID);

DataColumn assemblyNo = new DataColumn();
 assemblyNo.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
 assemblyNo.ColumnName = "assemblyNo";
dt.Columns.Add(assemblyNo);

 DataColumn job = new DataColumn();
 job.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
 job.ColumnName = "jobID";
dt.Columns.Add(job);

 DataColumn assemQTY = new DataColumn();
 assemQTY.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
 assemQTY.ColumnName = "assemblyQty";
dt.Columns.Add(assemQTY);
 DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
　
　　
 foreach (Excel.ListRow row in vstoListObject.ListRows)
{
　//This is the part i cant seem to get to work i just cant see why it shouldn't
　
 dataRow["assemblyNo"] = (int)(row.Range.Cells[1, 1]).ToString());

 dataRow["assemblyQty"] = (int)(row.Range.Cells[1, 2]).ToString());

 dataRow["jobID"] = (int)(row.Range.Cells[1, 3]).ToString());

dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
dataRow = dt.NewRow();


}

dt.AcceptChanges();

}

 catch(exception e)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());

 }
 return dt;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cast a string into an integer, which will raise an exception. You should use

```
int.Parse((row.Range.Cells[1, 1]).ToString())
```

Comment: Ok thanks, now it is saying "Input string was not in a correct format," I'm guessing this has to do with my list object row?

Comment: Most likely the cell is empty or contains an invalid number. It might contain a number with thousands separators, for instance, which will not be parsed correctly. I'm not an Excel interop expert, but you might try to just cast the cell to int without the ToString and seee the outcome.

Comment: Thank you I didn't think of that. For future reference it was returning an object still.  row.Range.Cells[1,1].Value.ToString() fixed the problem.